# Non-negative Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that if $A$ is an $n × n$ matrix and $A = B^tB$ then every eigenvalue of $A$ is non-negative.

I'm confused how the $A = B^tB$ relates to eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3):

If $Av=\lambda v$, then $\left\|Bv\right\|^2=v^tB^tBv=v^tAv=\lambda v^tv=\lambda \left\|v\right\|^2$.